# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) crash trying mergeSort

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, syntax-error

Hi so there are actually 2 questions. What does All paths through this function will call itself mean? Also I get a segmation fault at the places I put the errors.I tried debugging but I'm confused why it's not working. If someone could not just do this for me but also help explain what I did wrong that'll help alot.

```
  bool operator<=(const Record& rightObj) const {
     return this->k <= rightObj.k;
   }

template <typename T>
class LinkedList : public List<T> {
    protected:
        // represents an element in the linked list
        struct Node {
            T value;
            Node* next;

            Node(T v, Node* n = nullptr)
            : value(v), next(n) { }
        };

        // a pointer to the front of the list
        Node* head;

    private:
        // copy the values from the argument linked list to `this`
        void copy(const LinkedList<T>&);

        // merge sort algorithm
        void mergeSort(Node*&);

        void split(Node*, Node*&, Node*&);

        void merge(Node*&, Node*, Node*);

    public:
        // default constructor
        LinkedList();

        // copy constructor
        LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>&);

        // overloaded assignment operator
        LinkedList<T>& operator=(const LinkedList<T>&);

        // destructor
        virtual ~LinkedList();

        // add the argument to the end of the list
        virtual void append(const T&) override;

        // remove all elements in the list
        virtual void clear() override;

        // return the element at the given position (argument)
        virtual T getElement(int) const override;

        // return the current length of the list
        virtual int getLength() const override;

        // insert the given element (argument 2) at
        // the given position (argument 1)
        virtual void insert(int, const T&) override;

        // determine if the list currently empty
        virtual bool isEmpty() const override;

        // print the elements in the list starting at the given Node (argument)
        void print(Node*) const;

        // remove the element at the given position (argument)
        virtual void remove(int) override;

        // replace the element at the given position (argument 1) with
        // the value given (argument 2)
        virtual void replace(int, const T&) override;

        // sort the elements in the list using the algorithm (argument)
        //      4 --> merge sort
        virtual void sort(int) override;
};


template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::mergeSort(Node*& curr) {
    Node* n = curr;
    Node* a;
    Node* b;

    if (n == nullptr || n->next == nullptr) {
        return;
    } // if

// splits linked list
    split(n, a, b);

// recursive calls for sorting
    mergeSort(a);
    mergeSort(b);

// merging lists
    merge(n, a, b);
}  


template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::merge(Node*& curr, Node* A, Node* B) { //I get "All paths through this function will call itself here"
    // Node* result = nullptr;

    if (A == nullptr) {
        curr = B;
    } // if
    else if (B == nullptr) {
        curr = A;
    } // else if

    if (A->value <= B->value) { //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
        // cout << "TEST" << endl;
        // result = A;
        cout << "TEST" << endl;
        merge(curr, A->next, B); // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
        cout << "TEST" << endl;
    } // if
    else {
        // cout << "TEST" << endl;
        // result = B;
        merge(curr, A, B->next); // segmenation fault here
    } // else

    curr = A;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Off the top: `mergeSort` takes `curr` by reference, presumably with the purpose of updating it - but never actually updates it.

Comment: "All paths through this function will call itself" means that you have an infinite recursion. The function will always recursively call itself, and then that call will recursively call itself, and then that call...  , until the program runs out of stack space and crashes.

Comment: In `merge`, you handle the case where `A == nullptr` or `B == nullptr` - then go right ahead and dereference both `A` and `B`, which will crash if either is `nullptr`.